# Access declarations are deprecated in favor of using-declarations; suggestion: add the ‘using’ keyword

Tags: c++, tree, namespaces, binary-tree

I returned to one of my old C++ school assignments which implemented a binary tree. I have a file (Tree.cpp) that contains functions to insert, lookup, remove, etc nodes. At the top, I have `"using namespace std;"`. The warnings I am getting are caused by another file, SymTab.hpp, that looks like this:

```
#ifndef SYMTAB_H
#define SYMTAB_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.hpp"
using namespace std;

template <class Whatever>
class SymTab : private Tree<Whatever> {
public:
        Tree<Whatever> :: Insert;
        Tree<Whatever> :: Lookup;
        Tree<Whatever> :: Remove;
        Tree<Whatever> :: Write;
        Tree<Whatever> :: Set_Debug_On;
        Tree<Whatever> :: Set_Debug_Off;
};

#endif
```

Each of the lines after `public:` give a warning like:

> "SymTab.hpp:11:9: warning: access declarations are deprecated in
>   favour of using-declarations; suggestion: add the ‘using’ keyword
>   [-Wdeprecated] Tree :: Insert;", where "Insert is replaced
>   with each respective function name.

Any advice on namespaces and how to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Add the using keyword as it suggests?

Comment: Never ever ever put a using directive in a header. That means anything that includes that header gets the whole of `std`. If there's a conflict in there and they want to use your header, your header will probably lose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two separate issues. The one the compiler is talking about are the "access declarations" in `SymTab`. Simply change it to this:

```
template <class Whatever>
class SymTab : private Tree<Whatever> {
public:
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Insert;
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Lookup;
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Remove;
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Write;
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Set_Debug_On;
        using Tree<Whatever> :: Set_Debug_Off;
};
```

The other, totally unrelated issue is `using namespace std;` in a header file. That's not an error per se, but a **Bad Idea**<sup>TM</sup>. It causes the entire `std` namespace to be dumped into the global namespace for everyone who includes that header and there's *nothing they can do about it.* And it can lead to wonderful name conflicts with some common names like `transform`, `list` or `sort` which are defined in the `std` namespace. Just remove the `using` directive.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty thorough and resolved the warnings! As a follow up, many of my other header files have the using namespace std; at the top. Should I delete those lines?

Comment: @user3750325 Yes, you should definitely remove those!

Comment: @user3750325 if you're the only one that will ever edit those files - no, it's probably not worth the effort. If you're gonna share the project with anyone - yes, definitely.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I'd say "if you're the only one that will ever **use** those files."

Comment: @Angew I'd say there's no difference when you also take the second sentence of my comment into consideration :)